# Azure AD SSO Guest user can't login

Tags: azure-active-directory

On guest user login on redirect URI I got an error:

> AADSTS1000031: Application {App name} cannot be accessed at this time. Contact your administrator.

I'm using multi-tenant approach. The authorization URL looks good and it redirects me with such an error.

But I can't find any description of the error or configuration in the azure related to this error.

Also, "normal" users can log in without any issues.

I have such configuration in my Azure App:

[image: Azure app configuration]

Could you please advise how can I enable guest accounts support here?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you have not granted admin consent.

Go to **Azure Active Directory** within the Azure portal.
Go to **Application registrations**.
Select the Application based on the App-Id.
Go to **API Permissions**.
Click **Grant Admin consent**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent

Comment: Could you please advise what permission should be added because `openid` is not enough?

Comment: Probably email for starters so you can authenticate your guest user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: Well that isn't it because I've got all my permissions granted admin content and I'm still getting the error...

Answer (score 0):

Has this SSO been setup as an Enterprise application?
Or are you just trying to get a guest user logged in to your tenancy as a guest?
If it is the later just create a new Guest user within your tenancy, make sure you have the rights to to do this first.
Then have the guest user accept the email invitation they receive.
Confirm within Azure they have accepted the invite.
Also make sure they are using the same email address as the invite was sent to and not an alias, which can cause confusion.